how to change image color in CSS
I'm a css/html/js all that domain - beginner. so i am learning to code an app
I added a white png to a code:
    <div class="todo-app">
        <h2>To-Do list <img src="images/clock.png" alt=""></h2>
        <div class="row">
            <input type="text" id="input-box" placeholder="Add your text">
            <button>Add</button>
    </div>

.todo-app h2 img {
    width:150px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

Then i got the idea to turn the original white into another color, directly in the code (to fit my app theme)
How can i do this ?
i tried to use the filters
with for example :
filter: saturate();

or color changing commands :
Background:

/*or */

Color:


Well if you just need a solid color, use background-color and not an image.

Does this answer your question? Apply a filter with CSS to change colors of a picture

background is for background color of elemenet and color is for text

color of course has no effect on an image (that's for text color), and background(-color) could only have an effect, if your image had transparent parts.

@0stone0 it is a png image i want to use as an icon (a clock pictogram to be precise), i am not trying to use a png as a background haha. i am sorry if was not clear on my question.Aas i did say, i am a beginner.

In that case, use an SVG so you can change a path's color

If your image is a .png file including transparent areas and you mean to change the color in these transparent areas, you can indeed apply background-color to the image in CSS, which will then fill all transparent parts of the png.

In this example, sepia(100%) converts the white areas of the image to a sepia tone, which can then be further adjusted using hue-rotate and saturate to achieve the desired color effect. You can experiment with different values for hue-rotate and saturate to get the color you want.


.todo-app h2 img {
  width: 150px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  filter: sepia(100%) hue-rotate(180deg) saturate(500%);
  /* Rotate the hue by 180 degrees (changes white to a different color) */
}
<div class="todo-app">
  <h2>To-Do list <img src="https://www.amitree.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/the-pros-and-cons-of-paper-to-do-lists.jpeg" alt="image"></h2>
</div>



